# How to properly make a .map in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Can anyone help me to extract all links with an `href`?

This is the `map` code:

```
const image = images.map(img => img.links)

{ image.map(a => a.map( b => b.href))}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

This is the data

```
{
  'item': [
    {
      'data': [
        {'href': link}
      ]
    },
  ...
    {
      'data': [
        {'href': link}
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share some more code, what you are doing and what are you parsing?

Comment: I have a API [link](https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=saturn&page=2&media_type=image&year_start=1920&year_end=2019) and i need put all images in my react component

Comment: And how do you expect your output to look like? Just share the format of JSON object.

Comment: `const ImagesGallery = ({images}) => {
    useEffect( () => {
      onImagesGallery()
    }, [onImagesGallery])
const image = images.map(img => img.links)
  return (
      { image.map(a => a.map( b =>
        <div className={style.wrapper__container__content} key={b.index}>
          <img src={b.href ? b.href : noImage} alt=""/>
        </div>
        ))
      }
)
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  images: state.imagesGalleryPage.items,
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following structure, then use `flatmap` function:

```js
const data = [
  {
    'item': [
      {
        'data': [
          { 'href': 'link' },
          { 'href': 'link2' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'item': [
      {
        'data': [
          { 'href': 'link' },
          { 'href': 'link3' },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
];

 const result = data.flatMap(d =>
    d.item.flatMap(i =>
        i.data.map(h => h.href)));

 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can archive that by using `Array.map` and `Array.filter` to loop over the `'item'` of your object

```
var myItem = {
    'item': [
      {
        'data': [
          {'href': 'link1'}
        ]
      },
      {
        'data': [
          {'href': 'link2'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

var links = myItem['item'].map(el => el.data).reduce((rs, el)=> [...rs, el[0].href], [])
console.log(links)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that does not involve the usage of `.map` is using JSONPath, it helps to query through a JSON object with collections.

In your case you could do something like: `$.[*]..href` in order to get every href into an array.

JSONPath is similar to xPath, it is a query language that helps you retrieve data from collections / records.

More information about JSONPath:https://restfulapi.net/json-jsonpath/

Online playground: https://jsonpath.com

A quick library that I found in npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath

Comment: it is a good ideea bu i use with .map in react component and a think is not relevant for this

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with nested collections, you normally want to flatten result data structure.
So you do `flatMap` followed by `map`.

```
json.item.flatMap(x => x.data.map(image => image.href))
```